# Assignment operator is returning an "empty" instance when it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm implementing a stack just for practicing. So, in the main, I've got something like this:

```
Stack stack;
stack.push(element1;
stack.push(element2);

Stack copy;
copy = stack;
```

So I'm overloading the assignment operator because I want to generate new elements instances also (and not just copying the pointer of each element from one to another), as follows

```
Stack &Stack::operator=(const Stack &toCopy) {
    Stack* stack = new Stack;
    if (toCopy.first == NULL) return *stack;
    for (Node* actual = toCopy.first; actual != NULL; actual = actual->sig) {
        stack->push(actual->elem);
    }
    // In this state, *stack has 2 elements as it should
    return *stack;
}
```

Back in the main, the copy variable is not getting the changes... It's still empty as if the assignation had never happened. As if I had do just `Stack copy;` Could you explain me what is going on in here?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: it sounds like you have some basic misunderstandings about memory management. Your `operator=` leaks memory (the `new Stack` is never `delete`d). Also it never updates `*this`, instead you update the new stack and never do anything with the new stack.  There are probably a lot of errors in the other parts of your code that you didn't post. In future post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and life will get much easier if you stop using raw pointers.

Comment: You should probably modify `this` in `operator=`, not return a new stack.

Comment: Your operator= should be changing `this` and returning a reference to `this`, and not creating a new object and returning it.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not modifying the current object (i.e. `*this`).

You're just creating a new object by `new`, then returning it. Note for `copy = stack;`, it's equivalent to `copy.operator=(stack);`, note that the returned value is not used, it's just discarded (and causes memory leak), and `copy` isn't changed.

You should do something like:

```
Stack &Stack::operator=(const Stack &toCopy) {

    // do some work to clear current elements in *this
    // ...

    // add elements from toCopy
    for (Node* actual = toCopy.first; actual != NULL; actual = actual->sig) {
        this->push(actual->elem);
    }

    // operator= is supposed to return *this in general
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be misunderstanding the assignment operator. It works in the context of the object on the left of the equal sign. So your `::operator=(...)` should always be working on `*this` and should always return `*this` as well.

The `operator=(...)` that you posted is operating on a *new* Stack object that you've allocated on the heap, and you are operating on *it* instead of `*this`.

You can effectively replace `stack` with `this` in your code. I.e.:

```
Stack &Stack::operator=(const Stack &toCopy) {
    //Stack* stack = new Stack; // Don't do this.
    if (toCopy.first == NULL) return *this;
    for (Node* actual = toCopy.first; actual != NULL; actual = actual->sig) {
        this->push(actual->elem); // You could also just call push without "this->"
    }
    // In this state, *stack has 2 elements as it should
    return *this;
}
```